# want to delete image from folder and want to replace it with no image file without file uploading in core PHP

Tags: php

i want to delete image from folder and want to replace it automaticaly
with no image file without using file uploading in core php

> target_path);
>   @fopen($upload->target_path,'r'); echo 'target_path.'?id='.rand(6,100000).'" width=150
>   class=pic>';
>   fclose($upload->target_path); echo "**Copied file to "
>   .$upload->destination_path."**
>
> "; $filename = 
>   $upload->target_path; ?>

This code is deleting image but not
automatically replacing image with no image. i want to delete image
from folder and want to replace it automaticaly with no image file
without using file uploading in core php

Comment: So what do you actually mean by "to replace it with no image file"?

Comment: i mean that i want to replace it with other image on button click without using file upload

Comment: Now what, "no image" or "other image"? If "other image", then _which_ image?

Comment: This code is not readable. Please delete the code from the post, paste in the code again, and use the `{}` code tool, not the quote tool.

Answer (score 1):

To show a common image no image found, try this:

```
if( file_exists('file_path') )
{
    // show the actual image here
}
else
{
    // Display no_image_found.png instead of uploading new
    echo '<img src="images/no_image_found.png">';
}
```

`file_exists` check for the given image if it exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this code, may be this works for you:
<?php
$path = "uploads/"; 
$image = "vn.png";
$fpath = $path.$image;

if(unlink($fpath)){
   echo "Yes";
}else{
   echo "No";
}

$file = 'guest/noimage.png';
$newfile = 'uploads/noimage.png';
if(copy($file, $newfile)) {
  echo "Y";
}else{
  echo "N";
}

?>
```